# Excel INDIRECT returns with REF error

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I don't understand why my INDIRECT function does not work. I'm dynamically changing D2 value from a list.

```
=INDIRECT("'G:\Production\OPH 2015\"&D2&"'!"&"G4")
```

where

D2 = [Spreadsheet.xslx]Sheet1

G4 would be the value I want the formula to return with.

The same formula on its own returns the value 72.2% and looks like this:

```
='G:\Production\OPH 2015\[Spreadsheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!G4
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that already, same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't your formula that is incorrect, the `INDIRECT` formula will return `#REF!` if the workbook is closed.

I haven't tried this, but I believe this add-in will solve your problem: http://www.ashishmathur.com/tag/indirect-ext/

Comment: Thank you. Add-in isn't a solution, I would need it working elsewhere than my computer unfortunately. Would there be another way to reference closed spreadsheets dynamically?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Straight from the horse's mouth - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/151323

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"I don't understand why my INDIRECT function does not work"*

A: From the [MS Office Support Article for INDIRECT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

> - If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value.